# Issues of app.scss compile error in sencha touch

Tags: sass, sencha-touch, compass-sass

In my windows machine, i installed java, sencha cmd, sencha doc, ruby, compass and i generated one sencha application in that i try to compile app.scss file using the compass compile command but it gives the following error in command prompt:

when i run compass compile command it deletes app.css file and gives following error.

> C:\wamp\www\sass\resources\sass>compass compile 
>  modified config.rb
>     
>   clean C:/wamp/www/sass/resources/css 
>    delete C:/wamp/www/sass/resources/css/app.css 
>  DEPRECATION WARNING on line 1,
>   column 7 of C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gem
>   s/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_shared.scss: Unescaped
>   multiline strings are deprecated and will be removed in a future versi
>   on of Sass. To include a newline in a string, use "\a" or "\a " as in
>   CSS.
>
> WARNING: The compass/css3/shared module has been deprecated. You can
>   silence this warning by importing compass/css3/deprecated-support
>   instea d. Please be aware that module will be removed in the next
>   release.
>            on line 1 of C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/
>   stylesheets/compass/css3/_shared.scss
>            from line 3 of C:/wamp/www/sass/touch/resources/themes/stylesheets/senc
>   ha-touch/_base.scss
>            from line 22 of C:/wamp/www/sass/touch/resources/themes/stylesheets/sen
>   cha-touch/_default.scss
>            from line 4 of C:/wamp/www/sass/resources/sass/app.scss
>
> DEPRECATION WARNING on line 87 of
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass
>   -core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss: #{} interpolation  near operators will be simplified in a future version
>   of Sass. To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:
>
> unquote('"$moz-"#{$experimental-support-for-mozilla}
>   "$webkit-"#{$experimental
>   -support-for-webkit} "$opera-"#{$experimental-support-for-opera} "$microsoft-"#{ $experimental-support-for-microsoft}
>   "$khtml-"#{$experimental-support-for-khtml} ')
>
> You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.
>
> DEPRECATION WARNING on line 92 of
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass
>   -core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss: #{} interpolation  near operators will be simplified in a future version
>   of Sass. To preserve the current behavior, use quotes:
>
> unquote('"$ie6-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie6}
>   "$ie7-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie7} " $ie8-"#{$legacy-support-for-ie8}')
>
> You can use the sass-convert command to automatically fix most cases.
>
> WARNING: The compass/css3/box module is DEPRECATED and will be removed
>   in the ne xt release. Please use compass/css3/flexbox instead.
>            on line 4 of C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/
>   stylesheets/compass/css3/_box.scss
>            from line 4 of C:/wamp/www/sass/touch/resources/themes/stylesheets/senc
>   ha-touch/_base.scss
>            from line 22 of C:/wamp/www/sass/touch/resources/themes/stylesheets/sen
>   cha-touch/_default.scss
>            from line 4 of C:/wamp/www/sass/resources/sass/app.scss
>
> ```
> error app.scss (Line 6 of C:/wamp/www/sass/touch/resources/themes/stylesheet
> ```
>
> s/sencha-touch/_base.scss: File to import not found or unreadable:
>   blueprint/typ ography. Load paths:   Compass::SpriteImporter
>   C:/wamp/www/sass/resources/sass
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets 
>   C:/wamp/www/sass/touch/resources/themes/vendor/compass-recipes/stylesheets
>   C:/wamp/www/sass/touch/resources/themes/stylesheets) Sass::SyntaxError
>   on line ["6"] of C: File to import not found or unreadable: bl
>   ueprint/typography. Load paths:   Compass::SpriteImporter
>   C:/wamp/www/sass/resources/sass
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets 
>   C:/wamp/www/sass/touch/resources/themes/vendor/compass-recipes/stylesheets
>   C:/wamp/www/sass/touch/resources/themes/stylesheets Run with --trace
>   to see the full backtrace
>
> C:\wamp\www\sass\resources\sass>

Here sass is my folder name in www folder.
my app.scss file is as following

```
// The following two lines import the default Sencha Touch theme. If you are building
// a new theme, remove them and the add your own CSS on top of the base CSS (which
// is already included in your app.json file).
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

// Custom code goes here..

// Examples of using the icon mixin:
// @include icon('user');
.abc
{
    color: #fff;
}
```

my config.rb file is as following

```
# Get the directory that this configuration file exists in
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

# Load the sencha-touch framework automatically.
load File.join(dir, '..', '..', 'touch', 'resources', 'themes')

# Compass configurations
sass_path = dir
css_path = File.join(dir, "..", "css")

# Require any additional compass plugins here.
images_dir = File.join(dir, "..", "images")
output_style = :compressed
environment = :production
```

path of sencha sdk is as following

```
C:\wamp\www\sencha-touch-2.4.2-gpl\touch-2.4.2
```

Comment: The only error I see here is that you're trying to import files that don't exist (eg. blueprint).  Do you *have* blueprint installed?

Comment: No. I don't install any blueprint and i also tried in another windows laptop the same problem occurs.

Comment: How do you expect you're going to get a different result if you don't have blueprint installed?

Answer (score 1):

Compass is included in the Sencha CMD installation. You can compile the CSS by executing the command **sencha ant sass** from your application folder.

Comment: The CSS can be compiled without installing blueprint and a version of Compass that is compatible with the Sencha templates.

Comment: That's nice, but the OP is trying to reference blueprint, so I don't see how anything you've said so far resolves the problem.

Comment: The OP is trying to compile the CSS for a Sencha project. Newer versions of Compass are not compatible with the Sencha SASS templates. Using the sencha ant sass command to compile the CSS certainly resolves the issue. The OP is not using the correct approach to compile the CSS for a Sencha project.